# Laravel Zray - Failed to communicate with Zend Server

Tags: laravel, zend-server

I have recently started using Laravel Framework 5.6.7 and have everything running smoothly apart from the Zray toolbar it comes with. The toolbar displays the error: "Failed to communicate with Zend Server. See why..."

the link takes me to the troubleshooting page which is of no help:
http://files.zend.com/help/Z-Ray-Azure/Content/troubleshooting.htm

In my local environment I am using the homestead vagrant box:
Vagrant 2.0.2

I tried following this old post but Zray is already installed so I thought it must be a configuration issue:
https://laravel-news.com/installing-zend-z-ray-on-homestead

any ideas on how I can get this toolbar to work would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and it took a few days to get it resolved.  I have no idea if this will work for you but this is how I did it:

- Removed all vagrant boxes in my Homestead folder.  *vagrant box remove --all*  https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html
- Add vagrant box.  *vagrant box add/laravel/homestead*
- perform a git pull in the Homestead folder.  *git pull origin master*
- went to composer.json and deleted *"laravel/homestead": "^7"* (also deleted the trailing comma to ensure the JSON was valid).
- ran *composer update*.

Then after a vagrant up --provision (I wasn't sure if provision was needed but I put it just in case), I went to my site and no more Z-RAY issues!

I hope this helps someone else because this was NO fun to figure out.

Comment: in my case it was enough to run `git pull` and then `vagrant up --provision`, but this could be because my homestead box was relatively 'fresh' (installed yesterday).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
> zray: "true"
```

in your Homestead.yaml file